# Flutter - Alert Dialog showing multiple times inside listener

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, rxdart

I am using a [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to get a notification when a countdown timer has finished.
When i click the notification using `onSelectNotification` (callback of flutter_local_notification), I add a Subject (RxDart).

```
var selectNotificationSubject = PublishSubject<String>();

onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
 selectNotificationSubject.add(payload);
},
```

So the Subject is added successfully on the Stream.
I listen for the stream in `initState`. The `AlertDialog` is shown, but the problem is that it is shown multiple times for all the list with countdown timers.
I want to show the `AlertDialog` only for the timer that i clicked on the notification, not for all the timers that are available on the list.

A way to fix this may be to add to the `AlertDialog` widget a `id` so i can show it only once by the `id` of the countdown timer that is clicked on notification. `Widget showDialogById()`

```
subs = selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((event) async {
await showDialog(
 context: context,
 builder: (context) {

   return AlertDialog(
   title: Text("Repeat Timer ${timer.id}"),
   content: Text(
     "Do you want to repeat your timer ${timer.description} ?"),
    actions: [
     RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Repeat"),
      onPressed: () async {
           //Repeat timer logic here
      });
    ),
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you coded it, it is expected to spam repeatedly to show the dialog.
If you don't want a new trigger dialog show, create a boolean to control it, whatever the bool is true it won't show, otherwise it will show

Comment: Yes, but this way it will show the alert dialog of the first timer on the list.
I want to show the alert dialog for the timer that a clicked on the notification.
So in some way i should identify the notification to map it with the alert dialog that i want to show